# Linux: Useing AWK to Calculate Ratio Between 2 Values

Tags: linux, awk, syntax-error

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
abcd nasj uasdy 3452 2314134
abcd efgh sdfdsf 234553 9323454
abcd asdf asdfasdf 34545 5234523
abcd sdfa sadfad 435232434 3452435
```

Now I'm trying to calculate the ratio between the 5th column and 4th column using `awk` and I tried this:

```
BEGIN { printf "%10s %10s" "Column1:", "Ratio:%s" } 
        { printf "%10s %10f"  $1, ($6)/($5) }
```

But I keep getting an error saying:

```
awk: awkRatio.awk:1: fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
    `%10s %10sColumn1:'
            ^ ran out for this one
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you miss a comma after the `printf "..."`-part
try:

```
BEGIN { printf "%10s %10s", "Column1:", "Ratio:" } 
    { printf "%10s %10f",  $1, ($5)/($4) }
```

Comment: ...and should be `($5)/($4)`

Comment: True, OP stated fourth and fifth column

Comment: This still get a messy output.

Comment: @Jotne -- yeah, should have added a `\n` as you did. +1 for you to compensate :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some like this?

```
awk 'BEGIN { printf "%10s %10s","Column1:","Ratio:\n" } file
        { printf "%10s %10f\n" ,$1, ($5/$4) }'
  Column1:    Ratio:
      abcd 670.374855
      abcd  39.749882
      abcd 151.527660
      abcd   0.007932
```